# Sync JSON from DOM

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-router

I using react for my project. I rendering the page based on JSON.

The page has various component types from image to text Content.

Each component has delete option, image can be changed from desktop and text content can be changed by contenteditable.

On performing these actions, the JSON should be updated immediately, later based on an action I would save the modified JSON.

I don't want to write onchange handler for each component, instead as data loads from JSON, it's key map should return or update the respected JSON value.

I am storing the JSON in variable. If required I'm okay to stringify.

Comment: Please post any relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Store the JSON in a state property. The key of each component will be its index in the array that you will extract from the JSON. Every time you click the "delete" button, pass the key to the `onChange` function.

In the `onChange` function, destructure the JSON and save it into a temp variable. Delete the JSON object at the specified index from the JSON array. Set that temp variable back to state.